# Scrapy multipart form data request

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to parse orders from site. Orders loading via ajax and the request looks like:

> -----------------------------1662842698634843362034232373
>               Content-Disposition: form-data; name="query"
>               {
>               orders(skip: 30, limit: 30, filter: {less3bids: false,withoutMyBids: false,title: "tests",contractual: true}) {
>               total
>               filtered
>               orders {
>               id
>               type { id name }
>               }
>               }
>               }
>           -----------------------------1662842698634843362034232373--

I can't figure out how do I need send request. I tried:

```
def after_login(self, content):
    body = '''-----------------------------1662842698634843362034232373
                Content-Disposition: form-data; name="query"
                {
                orders(skip: 30, limit: 30, filter: {less3bids: false,withoutMyBids: false,title: "tests",contractual: true}) {
                total
                filtered
                orders {
                id
                type { id name }
                }
                }
                }
            -----------------------------1662842698634843362034232373--
            '''
            return scrapy.Request(
                url="https://somesite.com/graphqlapi?",
                method='POST',
                body=body,
                headers={
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1662842698634843362034232373'
                },
                callback=self.parse_orders)
```

But site returns error:

```
Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:1) Unexpected <EOF>\n\n1: \n   ^\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Firefox inspector return incorrect params. When I copied params from chrome, request works fine.